# Exit out of for loop after first condition is true

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase function which triggers onWrite to a specific ref on database than i take a snapshot of another ref and if the size of the value just added is equal to that of the snapshot i decrement 1 to snapshot and update it again.But if i have multiple sizes and amounts the loop keeps going and deletes everything.How can i exit out of the loop after the first condition is met.Here is my code:

```
exports.finalizeOrder = functions.database.ref('/orders/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    var orderData = event.data.val();
    return admin.database().ref('models/').child('females').child(orderData.id).once('value', function(data){
        var dbModel = data.val();
        for(var s = 0;s<dbModel.sizes.length;s++){
            if(Number(orderData.size) === dbModel.sizes[s].size){
                var index = dbModel.sizes.indexOf(dbModel.sizes[s])
                if(dbModel.sizes[s].amount > 0){
                    dbModel.amount = dbModel.amount - 1;
                    dbModel.sizes[s].amount = dbModel.sizes[s].amount -1;
                    if(dbModel.sizes[s].amount === 0){
                        dbModel.sizes.splice(index, 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        admin.database().ref('models/').child('females').child(orderData.id).update(dbModel);
        admin.database().ref('orders').child(event.data.key).update({status: 'proccesing'});
    })
});
```

Comment: you should probably use `break;` instead of `return;`. More info at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: it doesn't work with break; it gets out of the loop immediately

Comment: In your original question, you had a `return` inside your first IF. So, as said: put a `break;` statement in the position where you want the function to exit.

Comment: its not the loop porblem its the method. I am listening for on write and the function executes 2 times when the data is first recived and updated.i changed it to onCreate and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag and check it inside the conditional statement of your for loop. And set it to false whenever your condition is met. In the example below, I added it just inside the first `if`. You can set that anywhere inside the for loop you want when your condition is met.

```
exports.finalizeOrder = functions.database.ref('/orders/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
    var orderData = event.data.val();
    return admin.database().ref('models/').child('females').child(orderData.id).once('value', function(data){
        var dbModel = data.val();
        var conditionFlag = true; // Set condition flag to be true
        for(var s = 0;s<dbModel.sizes.length && conditionFlag ;s++){
            if(Number(orderData.size) === dbModel.sizes[s].size){
                conditionFlag = false; // Set conditionFlag to false wherever you want inside the loop so that the loop stops
                var index = dbModel.sizes.indexOf(dbModel.sizes[s])
                if(dbModel.sizes[s].amount > 0){
                    dbModel.amount = dbModel.amount - 1;
                    dbModel.sizes[s].amount = dbModel.sizes[s].amount -1;
                    if(dbModel.sizes[s].amount === 0){
                        dbModel.sizes.splice(index, 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        admin.database().ref('models/').child('females').child(orderData.id).update(dbModel);
        admin.database().ref('orders').child(event.data.key).update({status: 'proccesing'});
    })
});
```

Comment: it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was that i was listening for onWrite to the database ref i specified and that happens the first time i push the data and the second time i updated it thats why it was executing the function twice.I changed the onWrite with onCreate and it works perfect.